# Apply function to all first arguments of a nested list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching, nested-function

Currently, I have a nested list of rules of the form

```
lst1={1->a,2->{3->c,4->d,5->{6->f,7->{8->h,...}}}}
```

(where I *don't* know the length of the list). I would like to apply some function `z` to the "first" elements of the rules to get something of the form

```
lst2={z[1]->a,z[2]->{z[3]->c,z[4]->d,z[5]->{z[6]->f,z[7]->{z[8]->h,...}}}}.
```

Here's a little bit more info about the problem:

- I *don't* know the length of the (nested) list.
- A priori, I also *don't* know the lengths of any of the inner lists. That means both `{1->a,2->{3->c,4->d,5->{6->f,7->{8->h,...}}}}` and `{1->a,2->b,3->{4->d,5->{6->f,7->{8->h,...}}}}` are equally possible / valid.

Basically, I want everything of the form `Rule[_,_]` to be mapped to `Rule[z[_],_]`, but nothing I attempted (including `Apply`, `MapAt`, etc.) seems to work. I can't figure out the pattern matching to save my life.

One thing I *thought* would work is doing

```
lst1 /. {Rule[x_,y_]:>Rule[z[x],y]},
```

but this fails for inputs of the form `lst3={1 -> {2 -> {3 -> {4 -> 5}}}}`. For `lst3` as above, I would want to get out

```
lst4={z[1]->{z[2]->{z[3]->{z[4]->5}}}},
```

but instead I get `lst4b={z[1] -> {2 -> {3 -> {4 -> 5}}}}`.

Please help!

Answer (score 10):

```
list = {1 -> a, 2 -> {3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> {6 -> f, 7 -> {8 -> h, 9 -> j}}}};
```

**1. MapAt**

```
MapAt[z, list, Append[1] /@ Position[list, _Rule]]
```

{z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d,
z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h, z[9] -> j}}}}

**2. ReplaceAt**

```
ReplaceAt[list, (a_ -> b_) :> z[a] -> b, Position[list, _Rule]]
```

{z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d,
z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h, z[9] -> j}}}}

**3. Replace** (a shorter variant of Syed's solution

```
Replace[list, (a_ -> b_) :> z[a] -> b, -1]
```

{z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d,
z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h, z[9] -> j}}}}

Answer (score 8):

**Using `Replace` / `Map` :**

```
lst = {1 -> a, 2 -> {3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> {6 -> f, 7 -> {8 -> h}}}};

Map[Replace[
  HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] -> z[a] -> b], lst, {1, ∞}]
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @lericr:

```
Replace[lst, HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] :> z[a] -> b, Infinity]
```

would also work.

---

*Result:*

> {z[1] -> a,   z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d,     z[5] -> {z[6] -> f,
> z[7] -> {z[8] -> h}}}}

Comment: You don't need the Map, do you? Wouldn't `Replace[lst, HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] :> z[a] -> b, Infinity]` work?

Answer (score 5):

> the rules to get something of the form
>
> lst2={z[1]->a,z[2]->{z[3]->c,z[4]->d,z[5]->{z[6]->f,z[7]->{z[8]->h,...}}}}.

how about

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lst1={1->a,2->{3->c,4->d,5->{6->f,7->{8->h}}}}
lst1//.Rule[x_,y_]:>{z[x],y}
%//.{z[x_],any___}:>Rule[z[x],any]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

You could first find all the positions of `Rule`, and change the last index to 1:

```
lst1 = {1 -> a, 2 -> {3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> {6 -> f, 7 -> {8 -> h, 9 -> j}}}}
pos = ReplacePart[Position[lst1, Rule], {_, -1} -> 1]
```

Then use those positions in `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[f, lst1, pos]
```

> {f[1] -> a,
> f[2] -> {f[3] -> c, f[4] -> d,
> f[5] -> {f[6] -> f, f[7] -> {f[8] -> h, f[9] -> j}}}}

Answer (score 5):

```
lst = {1 -> a, 2 -> {3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> {6 -> f, 7 -> {8 -> h}}}}

lst //.  Rule[Except[_z, a_], b_] :> Rule[z @ a, b]
```

> {z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d, z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h}}}}

Answer (score 3):

Additional ways to use `ReplaceAll` and `Replace`:

```
lst = {1 -> a, 2 -> {3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> {6 -> f, 7 -> {8 -> h}}}};


lst /. Rule -> MapAt[z, 1]@*Rule
```

> {z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d, z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h}}}}

```
Replace[lst, Rule -> MapAt[z, 1]@*Rule, All, Heads -> True]
```

> {z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d, z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h}}}}

Answer (score 2):

An additional way to use `ReplaceAll` and `Cases`:

```
list = {1 -> a, 2 -> {3 -> c, 4 -> d, 5 -> {6 -> f, 7 -> {8 -> h, 9 -> j}}}};

 # /. Cases[#, Rule[x_, y_] :> x -> z[x], ∞] &@list
```

> {z[1] -> a, z[2] -> {z[3] -> c, z[4] -> d, z[5] -> {z[6] -> f, z[7] -> {z[8] -> h, z[9] -> j}}}}